# Why does the if-block not run for the final case?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Consider the following code, which counts how many of each element an array has:

```
public static void getCounts(int[] list) {
    int current = list[0];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++, count++) {
        if (list[i] > current) {
            System.out.println(current + " occurs " + count + timeOrTimes(count));
            current = list[i];
            count = 0;
        }
    }
   System.out.println(current + " occurs " + count + timeOrTimes(count));
}
```

For this question, please assume `list` is sorted in ascending order. If `list` is `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`, for example, the output is:

```
1 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 1 time
3 occurs 1 time
4 occurs 2 times
```

Now, if I get rid of the `println` that comes after the `for`-loop, i.e.

```
public static void getCounts(int[] list) {
    int current = list[0];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++, count++) {
        if (list[i] > current) {
            System.out.println(current + " occurs " + count + timeOrTimes(count));
            current = list[i];
            count = 0;
        }
    }
   // System.out.println(current + " occurs " + count + timeOrTimes(count));
}
```

Then using the same example input, the output becomes:

```
1 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 1 time
3 occurs 1 time
```

In other words, the `if` block **doesn't execute** if `list[i]` is the maximum value of the array. Why is this the case? For the example above, the index of the first `4` is `i = 4`, and `list[4] > 3`, so the conditional statement is met, but it still won't execute.

How can I adjust the code so that the `if` block will run for all cases?

Thanks

Comment: This question is at a beginner level but well thought-out and well-written, hitting all the necessary points.  I wish more of the beginner questions were as good as this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final `println` is necessary because you are triggering your print statement on a *change* in the value of `list[i]` and printing the result for the *previous* value.  At the end of the program there's no last "change" to be detected, so you need to handle the last case separately.

This (the need for a final operation after the loop) is a standard coding pattern that occurs any time a variable change in a sequence triggers an operation at the end of a batch.  One way of thinking about it is that there's a virtual value, one past the end of your array, that is always larger than any possible previous value and signals the end of data.  There's no need to test for it or actually implement it, but you still have to code the operation (in your case a `println`).

The operation could be much more complex, in which case you'd encapsulate it in a method to avoid code duplication.  Your code could benefit *slightly* from encapsulating the `println` in a method `outputCount(int value, int count)`.
For example

```
private void outputCount(int value, int count) {
    System.out.println(value + " occurs " + count + timeOrTimes(count));
}
```

For your use case it's almost not worth it, but if the end-of-batch operation were much more than 1 line of code I would certainly write a method for it instead of repeating the code.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much more sense. Thanks for the concise explanation. Just to make sure I've understood correctly, with for-loops that rely on a variable change, there should be some code that executes after the loop is complete to display that final change, right?

Comment: That is correct, when you deliberately run off the end of an array you have to handle the last batch of data that didn't have a change "after" it to trigger the summation (or whatever). See my expanded answer.

Comment: Would you mind showing how to encapsulate this code? I am a beginner in Java and haven't yet learned this concept.

Comment: Updated. You've already done it once with `timeOrTimes()` :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was what encapsulation was haha. So with the `outputCount` method created, I would still need to write it twice right? Once in the if-block and then once after the for-loop.

Comment: Encapsulation can have several meanings, but it just means to put a wrapper around something.  More formally it refers to the idea that a class hides its internals from the outside world and exposes only its API, or "contract" by which it interacts with its clients.